# I Don't Want To Upload Two Different Types of Apps In same Google Play Developer Account. What I Do?

Tags: google-play, admob

I have two different types of Apps(Shopping & Games) & don't want to publish under same Google Play Developer account. I want one Google Play Developer account named: "online shopping" and other named: "Amazing Games"

Q#1: Will I create two different Google Play Developer accounts($25+$25) or there is any option to create 2 accounts with different names in single Google Play Developer account?
Q#2: If I create two different Google Play Developer accounts, then can I create it with different name & emails with same Laptop & IP? 
Q#3: Then can I connect both with one Admob account?

Comment: Q1 -> create 2 separate account. No option to create 2 accounts in single account . Q2. -> Keep yes same laption and ip possible. Keep email and name different Q3 -> Yes you can use same admob id for different account, however its better to create separate admob account for each for accounting, report purposes. Also any suspension or issue with one account is limited to one..

Answer (score 2):

**Q#1: Will I create two different Google Play Developer accounts($25+$25) or there is any option to create 2 accounts with different names in single Google Play Developer account?**

There is no option to create 2 stores under 1 google play account. So the only option you have is to create 2 separate google play accounts (one for online shopping and the other for Games) Which is $50.

**Q#2: If I create two different Google Play Developer accounts, then can I create it with different name & emails with same Laptop & IP? Q#3: Then can I connect both with one Admob account?**

Yes, You can create different name & emails with same laptop & IP, but I don't recommend that because whenever you got a termination on one of your accounts the other get terminated also (Google states that in their Policies).

**Here's example of how google can detect multiple accounts and get all of your accounts suspended whenever one of them get terminated.**

- 2 Accounts Under the same Laptop & IP
- 2 Accounts with Gmails created under the same laptop (Even if you connect them separately)
- Same credit card used for the 2 accounts.

**How to avoid that?**

- Use separate laptop and separate connection for your accounts (You can use RDP or Proxies, Be prudent with that and use some premium proxies,RDPs or Socks)
- Use some OLD gmails, You can either purchase them or create new ones separately like stated above.
- Purchase your accounts with separate credit card (You can use Gift Cards, Don't use service like Entropay, Google Don't love them and your accounts won't last long).
- At last and not least, don't violate Google Policy to not get your account banned (Use your own Graphics, use keywords wisely and don't use copyrighted graphics or keywords).

Enjoy Google Play.